# Google runs billions of containers a week, what does that mean?

Tags: kubernetes

[Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/) is an open-source system for automating deployment, scaling, and management of containerized applications.

In the official site of Kubernetes it says "Google runs billions of containers a week", my question is: if a container here means a containerized application, does that mean Google have billions of applications? It simply sounds ridiculous, what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Well, they don't have to be billions of *different* applications. They deploy a number of applications (easily in the thousands I guess) across a large number of hosts (in the millions). And some of those may be short-lived, i.e. run thousands of times each day on every host.

Comment: It makes sense to me now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containers are great because they can scale out a single process across multiple physical/virtual host machines.

Google merely scales out their applications (Google.com, Gmail, Google+) across a large amount of hosts by using Borg (which was the inspiration for Kubernetes) and the container methodology.

Comment: Using kubernetes?

Comment: Google does not use Kubernetes: their cluster scheduler is called Borg. Kubernetes was heavily influenced by Borg but it is not the same codebase, and the feature set is likely very different. https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/44843.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Gmail itself can be millions of containers (just throwing out a number). It need not mean that many applications. There might also be short term jobs etc.